# Force Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal to not hide vertical scrollbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, modal-dialog, scrollbar, yii2

Vertical scrollbar is being hidden, when Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal appears, and returns, when modal is hidden. Since certain elements on my page varies its position on whether vertical scrollbar is or isn't visible -- this produces an overall not to good looking effect:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this and force vertical scrollbar to stay on screen all the time, even during displaying of Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal?

I'm using modals [generated by Yii2 framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-modal.html), but I doubt, that this is framework issue. Seems to be more like core Twitter Bootstrap 3 problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom CSS file that should be loaded after the bootstrap CSS add the following code:

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, the Bootstrap default code has certain preset CSS, which in this case will do `overflow: hidden` on the appearance of the modal.

To fix this issue, target the modal using a selector and add `overflow: scroll` to it, and make sure it comes after the Bootstrap CSS to get priority.

You could also slap an `!important` tag on it in the case that your CSS needs to come before the Bootstrap CSS for whatever reason.

Hope that helps.